# how to convert the content of subfolders recursive to pdf format?

Tags: command-line, convert-command

i have a folder with tons of subfolders containing png's. 
how can i step recursively through the subfolders and convert that files to pdf?
The pdf should have the name of the subfolder and be saved in the starting folder ...
there are no folders in folders, no problem with double names expected.
i'm beginner, tried other ideas, but terrible things happend ...

joe

Comment: Also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011550/how-can-i-convert-all-video-files-in-nested-folders-batch-conversion

Comment: @muru how? ffmpeg does not convert to PDF.

Comment: @AllanBertelsen oh, copy-pastad'd. That was supposed to be https://askubuntu.com/questions/749882/ (with BMP/PNG replaced with PNG/PDF)

Comment: @muru yes that's much better. Combined with the fact that convert also takes png to pdf as you mention.

Comment: no video ... simply open one subfolder, make convert command, next subfolder, convert ... until there are no more subfolders

Comment: @muru Not exact duplicate, plus title is misleading. In the opening line of that post OP stated "I have a directory on my machine with 100s of images in it" , so they have a flat directory actually, nothing recursive. This question here has non-flat directory tree.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy yet OP there explicitly asks for recursive, and the answer has a recursive version. So what's the point of your objection?

Answer (score 1):

A script like this would do the trick

```
#!/bin/bash
for D in `find . -mindepth 1 -type d`
do
    convert `ls -1v $D/*.png` $D.pdf
done
```

Comment: 1) Do not parse `ls` command's output ever: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs  2) Do not use backticks in general 3)  Either use glob or use `find` directly, don't combine them: https://dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html. Not going to downvote this answer, but this is bad quality over all

Comment: Very interesting feedback. Thank you for your comments and the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming directory tree as so:

```
$ tree pngs/
pngs/
├── png1
│   ├── hw3.png
│   └── test.png
└── png2
    ├── hw3.png
    └── test.png
```

You can achieve what you ask the following way:

```
for dir in pngs/*; do 
    cd "$dir"
    convert ./*.png "$(basename "$dir")".pdf
    cd - 
done
```

The result:

```
$ tree pngs/
pngs/
├── png1
│   ├── hw3.png
│   ├── png1.pdf
│   └── test.png
└── png2
    ├── hw3.png
    ├── png2.pdf
    └── test.png
```